# Finding a suitable universe for a given structure

Tags: functions, logic, relations, model-theory, universal-algebra

I am new to this forum, so I hope my mathematical way of writing here is correct, as I have not done it much before. :(

I am taking my logics class currently and stumbled upon the following task.

We are given a structure $\mathcal{G}$ from universal algebra entailing the **domain** (or **universe**) **$G$** := $\wp(\mathbb{N})$ (the power set of natural numbers), a **signature** $\omega:=\{\cup,\cap\ , ^c \}$ where $\{\cup,\cap\, ^c \}$ is the set of **function symbols** and $^c$ is merely the complement of $\{G'^c= \mathbb{N} \setminus G'$  |  $G'\in\wp(\mathbb{N})\}$ - in accord with the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)). (We have a purely algebraic structure without relation symbols).

Furthermore, we are given two subsets of the universe $\wp(\mathbb{N})$ (that are, again, universes in themselves) with

**(1)** $\{G'' \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ | $G''$ finite}.

**(2)** $\{G'' \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ | $G''$, $G''^c$ infinite}.

And, the way I understood it, we are supposed to prove if there exists a substructure of $\mathcal{G}$ over the universe (1). If not, we shall give the smallest substructure of $\mathcal{G}$ which *contains* (1) . The same for universe (2).

So, what I do know is that a substructure $\mathcal{F}$ (with its universe $F$) has to fulfill the properties

**i.** The domain of $\mathcal{F}$ is contained in the domain of $\mathcal{G}$, i.e. $|\mathcal{F}| \subseteq |\mathcal{G}|$. (or $F\subseteq G$)

**ii.** $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ have the same signature $\omega(\mathcal{F}) = \omega(\mathcal{G}) $.

Now, I do understand that, trivially, (1) cannot be the universe of a substructure of $\mathcal{G}$ because its subsets are not closed under the complement, and (2) cannot be, either, since its subsets are not closed under union. However, I don't really know how I could find the smallest substructure of $\mathcal{G}$ that would contain (1), (2), or both. So I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks so much,
Gianna

Comment: In (1) and (2), is it $G \subseteq \mathbb N$, as you have it, or $G \subseteq \wp(\mathbb N)$? In the former case (as it is) it's rather trivial, and the same for both questions, unless I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: It is indeed $G \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. I do not see however how it is trivial... I hope I have not written any conflicting/confusing notations?

Comment: In that case, the substructure generated by $G$ has the underlying set $$\{\varnothing, G, \mathbb N\setminus G, \mathbb N\}.$$ And the operations are the same as in $\wp(\mathbb N)$. But maybe this is not what you want?

Comment: Do you mean that your proposed universe with its signature is the smallest substructure which entails (1) and (2)? And if you think it is, could you explain why it entails (1) and (2)? Property i. and ii. are trivial obviously.

Comment: If $G\subseteq\mathbb N$ (either finite or infinite), then the above set is closed under the operations of $\omega$, and it's the smaller such set containing $G$: indeed, if $G$ belongs to any such set, then so does $G^c=\mathbb N\setminus G$, and then also $\varnothing=G\cap G^c$ and $\mathbb N=G\cup G^c$.

Comment: A comment on the writing. It seems you've used the letter $G$ for three completely different things here: (a) The domain of $\mathcal{G}$, $G = \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$. (b) A variable ranging over $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ in the definition of $^c$. (c) A subset of $\mathbb{N}$ used in specifying the subsets of $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ that you're asking about in (1) and (2). This is quite confusing!

Comment: Here are some other things that I'm confused about. Can you clarify? (1) You say that $^c$ should be a relation symbol. What is the arity of this relation symbol? Is it binary, so that $(X,Y)$ satisfies the relation if and only if $Y = X^c$? (2) Are you asking about a single fixed finite $G\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, or about the set of all  $\{G\subseteq \mathbb{N}\mid G\text{ is finite}\}$? I think the second option is what you meant, but it's not totally clear. (3) What do you mean by "entails"? Did you maybe mean "the smallest substructure that *contains* [the set defined by] (1)"?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first question on Stackexchange so I didn't know the exact conventions. :( Regarding your points, (1) The arity (if I'm not mistaken) is binary, when looking at how $^c$ is defined in the task. (2) I do mean the latter indeed. Any arbitrary set that is a subset of (1) or (2). I'm already sure they can't be a universe for a potential substructure so there's that (3) I do mean contains. I'm sorry, English is not my first language, I thought entail and contain would imply the same thing. @amrsa: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I have just edited the question, hope I could enhance the readability.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - it's much clearer now. Welcome to Math Stackexchange!

Comment: Thank you:)) happy to be here!

Comment: Ah! This new version looks better to me. You see, saying the generating set is something like $G=\{F\subseteq\mathbb N:F\text{ is finite}\}$ is equivalent to $G\subseteq\wp(\mathbb N)$ and $F$ is finite, whenever $F \in G$. Not trivial anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $\mathcal{A}$ is an structure and $B\subseteq A$ is a subset of the domain $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$, then $B$ is the domain of a substructure of $A$ if and only if $B$ contains all the interpretations of constant symbols in the language and is closed under all the interpretations of function symbols in the language. That is, if $c$ is a constant symbol, we require that $c^{\mathcal{A}}\in B$, and if $f$ is an $n$-ary function symbol and $b_1,\dots,b_n\in B$, we require that $f^\mathcal{A}(b_1,\dots,b_n)\in B$.

For an arbitrary subset $B\subseteq A$, there is a smallest subset $\langle B\rangle$ containing $B$ which is the domain of a substructure. This is called the *substructure generated by $B$*.  Intuitively, $\langle B\rangle$ consists of all elements of $A$ which can be "constructed" from the constants and the elements of $B$ by applying the functions. More formally, this can be described by $$\langle B\rangle = \{t^\mathcal{A}(b_1,\dots,b_k)\mid t(x_1,\dots,x_k) \text{ is a term, and }b_1,\dots,b_k\in B\}.$$

Ok, so in the situation of your question, we have the structure $\mathcal{G} = (\wp(\mathbb{N}),\cup,\cap,^c)$, where $\cup$, $\cap$, and $^c$ are function symbols (there are no constant symbols). As you pointed out, neither of the given sets is the domain of a substructure, since (1) is not closed under complements and (2) is not closed under intersections or union. So what are the substructures they generate?

*Hints:*

(1) The finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are closed under intersections and unions, but not under complements. So as a first step we can throw in their complements to get $\{X\subseteq \mathbb{N}\mid X\text{ is finite}\}\cup \{X\subseteq \mathbb{N}\mid X^c\text{ is finite}\}$. Is this set closed under intersections, unions, and complements?

(2) The set $F = \{X\subseteq \mathbb{N}\mid X\text{ and }X^c\text{ infinite}\}$ is closed under complements, but not under intersections and unions. Which subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ can you make by intersecting two sets in $F$? What about by taking the union of two sets in $F$?

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer!! I guess what confuses even me a little here is that the task does not explicitly state whether $^c$ is actually a function symbol or a relation symbol. One of our tutors here said that it has to be closed under all operations. Perhaps, all of the operations are merely function symbols. But then again - would it be a valid structure with only function symbols, and no relation symbols at all?

Comment: I see. In your question you wrote that $^c$ is a relation symbol, so I went with that. If the problem does not specify, you should probably ask your professor for a clarification - but I think it's very likely that $\cap$, $\cup$, and $^c$ are all intended to be function symbols. There is no requirement for a structure to have relations symbols - the set of relation symbols can be empty (and the same for function symbols and constant symbols).

Comment: what a timing, I just got a mail from our professor!! :) he said that they are all intended to be function symbols. He forgot to say that in the task apparently. So I am right, both (1) and (2) cannot be right! which also leaves me with my initial question, tho... :( if $^c$ was a relation symbol, trivially, it would have been (1) as a substructure!

Comment: @GiannaAlbertini I've edited my answer to address the new version of the question.

Comment: @GiannaAlbertini Take a little bit of your time to check this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are satisfied with this answer, you might want to accept it, and perhaps even to upvote it, since you already have the necessary reputation score.

Comment: Thank you very much professor, I was able to figure out the rest of the proof thanks to your hints :D @amrsa did just that ;)